# Difference between audio and sound settings

Tags: audio, terminology, semantics

I have an application which has settings where user can define what file will be played on different events (complete, cancel etc.)

What is the difference between words *audio* and *sound* (settings) in computer program? Or is there difference at all? In my case what would be the settings called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is somewhat subjective, but to me *audio* is somewhat lower level than *sound*.

*Audio settings* would be things like "sample rate", "number of bits", "mono/stereo", etc.

*Sound settings* would be things like "enable sound effects", "enable background music", "volume", etc.

Answer (score 0):

From what you describe those settings are the logical choice would be `sound settings`. `audio` would imply that he changes the way the sounds are played, not what the actual sounds are.

On the other hand `sound` is a homonym so you may want to avoid it.

It's hard to make a competent choice because the two words are perfect synonyms (each of them can be used in place of the other in any context).